# How to resolve the red warnings in the Problems view in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I just update my Android Studio version to 4.1.1 and noticed that upon it restarting, I am getting red lines (as if there is a compilation error) in my project structure, all of which leading to my drawable folder, however, I don't see any issues upon expanding that folder...

[image: Problems]

The same holds true when I change the view type to "Project", but there is shows the images as well, but not of the actual images seem to have any issues.

When I change the view type from "Problems" to "Android" I still see the red lines, but it is now only at the root folder "app"

[image: Android]

I have tried restart/Invalidate Cache but that does not make this go away.

I can still run and compile my app, but this red line is really annoying and I would like to resolve it.